# Ubuntu 14.04 Apache Virtual Hosts Redirecting to Another Virtual Host?

Tags: php, html, apache, dns

I have a web server running three websites at the same time. I used the following tutorial to make the first two websites work https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-apache-virtual-hosts-on-ubuntu-16-04

After I added the third site using the tutorial, the third site automatically redirects to my second site.

First site: littlegreentech.ca

Second Site: uss-artemis.com

Third site: southkentbarbell.com

If anyone has any ideas why the server would be redirecting my third site to the second site, I am open to any and all ideas and questions. Thank you so much in advance.

The virtual host file contents are as follows.

uss-artemis.com.conf:

```
    ServerAdmin e**********@gmail.com
    ServerName uss-artemis.com
    ServerAlias www.uss-artemis.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/uss-artemis.com/public_html



    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
```

RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =u
RewriteRule ^ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [END,NE,R=permanent]

southkentbarbell.com.conf:

```
    ServerAdmin webmaster@southkentbarbell.com
    ServerName southkentbarbell.com
    ServerAlias www.southkentbarbell.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/skbb/public_html



    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
```

RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =u
RewriteRule ^ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [END,NE,R=permanent]

Comment: Can you show the virtual host conif details in apache config file?

Comment: I added the conf file contents to my original post. Thank you for looking!